# How to classify multiple objects in an R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, stata, text-classification

This is just a small portion of the data frame I am working with:

```
id       drug        start        stop          dose    unit    route   
2010003  Amlodipine  2009-02-04   2009-11-19    1.5     mg      Oral    
2010003  Amlodipine  2009-11-19   2010-01-11    1.5     mg      Oral      
2010004  Cefprozil   2004-03-12   2004-03-19    175     mg      Oral    
2010004  Clobazam    2002-12-30   2003-01-01    5       mg      Oral
```

I have a Stata `do` file, which shows what I am trying to do:

```
replace class = "ACE Inhibitor" if strmatch(upper(drug), "CAPTOPRIL*")
replace class = "ACE Inhibitor" if strmatch(upper(drug), "ENALAPRIL*")
replace class = "ACE Inhibitor" if strmatch(upper(drug), "ENALAPRILAT*")
replace class = "ACE Inhibitor" if strmatch(upper(drug), "FOSINOPRIL*")
replace class = "ACE Inhibitor" if strmatch(upper(drug), "LISINOPRIL*")
replace class = "ACE Inhibitor" if strmatch(upper(drug), "RAMIPRIL*")
replace class = "Acne Medication" if strmatch(upper(drug), "ADAPALENE*")
replace class = "Acne Medication" if strmatch(upper(drug), "ADAPALENE/BENZOYL PEROXIDE*")
replace class = "Acne Medication" if strmatch(upper(drug), "BENZOYL PEROXIDE*")
replace class = "Acne Medication" if strmatch(upper(drug), "BENZOYL PEROXIDE/CLINDAMYCIN*")
replace class = "Acne Medication" if strmatch(upper(drug), "ISOTRETINOIN*")
replace class = "Acne Medication" if strmatch(upper(drug), "ERYTHROMYCIN/TRETINOIN*")
replace class = "Acne Medication/Acute Promyelocytic Leukemia Medication" if strmatch(upper(drug), "TRETINOIN*")
replace class = "Alpha Agonist" if strmatch(upper(drug), "XYLOMETAZOLINE*")
replace class = "Alpha Blocker" if strmatch(upper(drug), "DOXAZOSIN*")
replace class = "Alpha Blocker" if strmatch(upper(drug), "PHENOXYBENZAMINE*")
replace class = "Alpha Blocker" if strmatch(upper(drug), "PHENTOLAMINE*")
replace class = "Alpha Blocker" if strmatch(upper(drug), "PRAZOSIN*")
replace class = "Alpha Blocker" if strmatch(upper(drug), "TAMSULOSIN*")
replace class = "Alpha Blocker" if strmatch(upper(drug), "TERAZOSIN*")
replace class = "Alpha/Beta Blocker" if strmatch(upper(drug), "CARVEDILOL*")
replace class = "Alpha/Beta Blocker" if strmatch(upper(drug), "LABETALOL*")
replace class = "Alpha-1 Agonist" if strmatch(upper(drug), "PHENYLEPHRINE*")
replace class = "Alpha-1 Agonist" if strmatch(upper(drug), "MIDODRINE*")
replace class = "Alpha-2 Agonist" if strmatch(upper(drug), "CLONIDINE*")
replace class = "Alpha-2 Agonist" if strmatch(upper(drug), "DEXMEDETOMIDINE*")
replace class = "Anaesthetic, general" if strmatch(upper(drug), "KETAMINE*")
replace class = "Anaesthetic, general" if strmatch(upper(drug), "THIOPENTAL*")
replace class = "Anaesthetic, local" if strmatch(upper(drug), "BENZOCAINE*")
replace class = "Anaesthetic, local" if strmatch(upper(drug), "BUPIVACAINE*")
replace class = "Anaesthetic, local" if strmatch(upper(drug), "BUPIVACAINE/FENTANYL*")
replace class = "Anaesthetic, local" if strmatch(upper(drug), "TETRACAINE*")
replace class = "Anaesthetic, local" if strmatch(upper(drug), "XYLOCAINE*")
replace class = "Anaesthetic, local/Antiarrythmic" if strmatch(upper(drug), "LIDOCAINE*")
replace class = "Anaesthetic, local/Antiseptic" if strmatch(upper(drug), "HEXYLRESORCINOL*")
replace class = "Anaesthetic, topical" if strmatch(upper(drug), "LIDOCAINE/PRILOCAINE*")
replace class = "Anaesthetic, topical" if strmatch(upper(drug), "PROPARACAINE*")
replace class = "Analgesic" if strmatch(upper(drug), "ACETAMINOPHEN*")
replace class = "Analgesic" if strmatch(upper(drug), "BELLADONNA & OPIUM SUPPOSITORY*")
```

I want to do the same classification in R but I do not know Stata.

Note that drugs can have more than one `class`.

Any advice and help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The solution might vary depending on how consistent the names are in the "drug" column. What is the result of `unique(your_data_frame$drug)`?

Comment: The code in your Stata `do` file means replace variable `class` with `ACE Inhibitor` if  the value of variable `drug` in upper case begins with `CAPTOPRIL`, irrespective of what follows.

Comment: The sample data is not very meaningful since none of the drugs listed at the top of the question appear in the Stata script shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first step I would import all the drug data from your Stata script (assuming the data is not in a clean, usable format already):

```
drug_class_data <- read.table("Desktop/stata_script", header=FALSE, sep='"',stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  
drug_class_data <-drug_class_data[,c(2,4)] 
colnames(drug_class_data) <- c('Drug_class','Drug')
```

Remove the trailing * - used as a wildcard in the Stata script

```
drug_class_data$Drug = gsub("\\*", "", drug_class_data$Drug)
```

This gives you a dataframe with 2 columns ('Drug_class' & 'Drug') - the line extracts any data in quotes from each line of the Stata script (Highlighted in bold below):

> replace class = "**ACE Inhibitor**" if strmatch(upper(drug), "**CAPTOPRIL***")

I would then save that as a file which you can then import as needed (I assume that this data isn't already available like this as you have hardcoded all these values in the Stata example).

```
write.csv(drug_class_data, file = "drug_class_data.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

From there it depends upon whether you want:

1) Multiple rows for each drug instance with a single text column where the drug class is explicitly specified. The number of rows per drug = number of drug classes it is a member of.  There are some advantages to this approach but it leads to a lot of duplicated data.

2) A single row for each drug and multiple boolean columns for each drug class - "ACE Inhibitor", "Acne Medication", etc -containing a binary TRUE or FALSE to indicate whether it is a member of that class.

Personly I would favour option 2 as a starting point for downstream analysis.  (As you mention drugs are likely to be categorised under multiple classes, also several drug classes appear hierarchical - 'Anaesthetic, local' could be a parent term for 'Anaesthetic, local/Antiarrythmic', 'Anaesthetic, local/Antiseptic' etc)

Extract all unique classes of drugs from your data frame into a list:

```
drug_class_list <- unique(drug_class_data[,1])
```

I would then use the ugly code below to create a new dataframe:

```
create_flat_table <- function(df_drugs, df_classes){   
# Extract list of drug classes present in df

class_list <- unique(df_classes[,1])  
# Reiterate over this list creating a new column in the drug df and populating it with data   
drugs <- as.list(drug_data['drug'])  
results <- df_drugs   
for(class in class_list){   
class_drugs <- df_classes[df_classes$Drug_class == class,]   
boolean_list <- toupper(df_drugs[,2])%in%class_drugs[,2]
results <- cbind(results, boolean_list )   }   
colnames(results) <- c(colnames(df_drugs), class_list)   
return(results) }

combined_df <- create_flat_table(drug_data, drug_class_data)
```

The resulting dataframe will look like:

[image: Resulting Dataframe]

Note that in this example I have changed the data so that at least one drug in your toy dataset will match a class in your abbreviated list of drug classes.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `statscript` and `DF` are as shown reproducibly in the Note at the end.  Then extract out the class and pattern into `translate` and left join `DF` to it using the glob pattern `pat`.

```
translate <- read.table(text = statascript, as.is = TRUE)[c(4, 7)]
names(translate) <- c("class", "pat")

library(sqldf)
sqldf("select DF.*, translate.class 
       from DF 
       left join translate on upper(class) glob pat")
```

### Note

```
# just first few lines for illustration
Lines <- '
replace class = "ACE Inhibitor" if strmatch(upper(drug), "CAPTOPRIL*")
replace class = "ACE Inhibitor" if strmatch(upper(drug), "ENALAPRIL*")
replace class = "ACE Inhibitor" if strmatch(upper(drug), "ENALAPRILAT*")
'

Lines2 <- "
id       drug        start        stop          dose    unit    route   
2010003  Amlodipine  2009-02-04   2009-11-19    1.5     mg      Oral    
2010003  Amlodipine  2009-11-19   2010-01-11    1.5     mg      Oral      
2010004  Cefprozil   2004-03-12   2004-03-19    175     mg      Oral    
2010004  Clobazam    2002-12-30   2003-01-01    5       mg      Oral"

statascript <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
DF <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```